# I am trying to use H2 in-memory database and custom @GenericGenerator strategy but internally my customeId generator is not getting called

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am creating a spring boot application using H2 database and I want to create a `customId` generator using some prefixes but it is not getting created.

As I have created `FilmsIdGenerator` by extending `SequenceStyleGenerator` as below. But the custom generator is not getting called while generating values for the primary column `show_id`. It is not appending the prefix that I have mentioned like B_00001 should be ideally the format created for primary key `show_id` but it is creating default s1,s2 ... can anyone please help

```java
public class FilmsIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {
    
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private String valuePrefix;
    
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String numberFormat;
    
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
            Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params,
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER,
                params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER,
                params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

above given is my custom id generator class and it should create primary key id as in B_00001 format. But it is taking default sequence format ie s1,s2, .. etc I am using H2 database. Can anyone please tell me why the custom generator is not getting called on my primary key JPA is generating the primary key id for persistence?

Below given is entity class here I am passing my customidgenerator as strategy and 3 input parameters I need to generate primary key to be of format B_00001 but it is generating s1,s2,.. ie it is taking
default sequence format. Why my custom id generator is not getting applied to it.

As I have created customIdgenerator by implementing SequenceStyleGenerator as below but the custom generator is not getting called while generating the primary column show_id.It is not appending the prefix that i have mentioned like B_00001 should be ideally the format created for primary key show_id but it is creating def

```
@Table(name = "FILMS") 
public class Films implements Serializable, Comparator {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "film_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "film_seq", strategy = "com.films.demo.model.generator.FilmsIdGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = FilmsIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "50"),
            @Parameter(name = FilmsIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "B_"),
            @Parameter(name = FilmsIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d") })
    @Column(name = "show_id")
    private String show_id;
```

Comment: And please dont close the question,if you dont understand please let me know i will explain

Answer (score 0):

I have used this with db2 database .It is generating the correct show_id with correct prefix. This issue
seems to be only with h2 in memory database

Comment: It is working with h2 database also you can use the same code.I was passing the generated id as well

Comment: can you please explain what you did differently for h2 database? i am facing the same problem